# How to load and parse chunk of data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing

I use `NSURLConnection` to load xml from server when starting the app, but mostly I just get the very first lines of xml to check the version and stop parsing the rest. As loading the whole xml takes time which I dont need it often. Is it possible to only parse the first load of `didReceiveData` and then stop loading the rest?

Thanks

Comment: I parse with NSXMLParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done libxml2 SAX parser.. It has the capacity to parse the data as it comes in.. for more info refer this... http://www.jamesh.id.au/articles/libxml-sax/libxml-sax.html

Comment: There's a class `NSXMLParser` in Cocoa that provides a wrapper to libxml2's SAX parser.  It's probably easier to use.

Comment: but on ray wenderlich's blog I read that they both are different parser and NSXMLParser is a DOM parser.. correct me if I am wrong... see this.. in this there is table where he says that you cannot parse while downloading.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: No.  NSXMLParser is an event driven SAX parser. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html.  The confusion probably arised from the fact that the DOM objects also start NSXML...

Comment: Note that the blog you refer to was written before NSXMLParser had the `-initWithStream:` method added.

Comment: can you point me to a sample where NSXMLParser has been used to parse a stream of data...? thanx in advance

Comment: @JeremyP: I use initWithData to init the parser and i get error at the end of the first chunk of parsing and also the rest of xml since it doesnt look like an verified xml to parse? or it is something else? should i use initWithstream instead? can you explain alittle more i am very new to iphone, thaks

Comment: @Finutv: Yes, initWithStream is what you need, but `initWithContentsOfURL` might also work as long as it is not so stupid as to download all of the data from the URL before starting the parser.

Comment: i found this maybe it will help:http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/306924-asynchronous-downloading-and-parsing-of-xml.html

Comment: just wonder when i should call the doMagicParsingStuff. as i want to parse right after loading (in didReceivedata), do you think i should call it in this method?

Comment: i extend following delegates in interface but it seems not enough as i have warning for all of the method in that link:<NSXMLParserDelegate, NSStreamDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate>

Comment: i think you can write it any where but the parser will work once it starts getting the data from the stream.. and also please start accepting answers for your questions or no one will answer them. I am helping you out in this one because this is something even I wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you two which is helping me. i just accepted it, sorry i am new user in stackoverflow and i havenot get use to it properly.will be better